# Auto-collapse all childs before open another child(Mbostock D3 Collapsible decision tree)

Tags: d3.js, decision-tree

I'm creating a web app with the collapsible decision tree and i need to **prevent the user from opening more than one 'last tree child'**, so if a last child is open, and the user tries to open another child, first close all childs and the open the selected one.

[image: This is what i should prevent]
[image: this is the way it should work, with only 1 last child opened]

Comment: If you start from [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083), you would need to call the `collapse()` function on click for all nodes that are not a parent (or grandparent) of the node that has been clicked.

Comment: Thanks Lars Kotthoff, i tried your example, but i'm stuck, i can't get them closed, i added the collapse function on the click event, checking the depth and if it is parent or not... Could you help me, do you have an example? Thanks

Comment: It may be easier if you start by simply closing everything on click. I don't know of an example that does what you want.